# Get Shortcut target path in C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, shortcut

How can I get a shortcut path in UWP C#?

I have seen several answers pertaining to getting .lnk targets using COM objects but in UWP I cannot seem to add a reference to the Shell interop.

in my application, I have a requirement to interprit a shortcut to a file, and read the shortcut  target file's contents, and read a shortcut to a folder, as the traversal of that shortcut target folder's contents. Think of it as a symlink. I want to be able to interprit shortcuts as a symlink and that requires getting the target of a shortcut, because not all users are knowledgable enough of what a symlink is.

I can't even find a good starting point, besides handling the file format myself. Is there a "Windows" way to do this?

Comment: why do you want to get shortcut target path? Does you want make shortcut for your uwp app or any other thing?

Comment: @Nico I edited the question to match your inquiry.

Comment: Is your app's type desktop or uwp ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT It is UWP; if it was plain desktop I would just import the Shell COM, but sadly I cannot find the way to do this in UWP. Possibly due to the sandbox nature of UWP...? But I would still like to get a link target for a file which I have file access permissions.

Comment: Currently, `UWP` does not provide such api that similar as **symlink**. So you could post your feature request in [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I created a feature request in UserVoice. Could you post that the feature is not available as an answer, so that this question can be closed?

Comment: Sure, I will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get a shortcut path in UWP C#?

Currently, UWP does not provide such api that similar as symlink. So you could post your feature request in [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent).